# How to pass data from HTML through directive to controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I pass data from html using directive

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
   <tempdir color="red"></tempdir>
</div>
```

and use it

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive("tempdir", function() {
  return {
    template: "<div id={{color}}> ... </div>",
    scope: {
      color: "@"
    }
  };
});

app.controller('main', function($scope) {
  // HOW TO CONSOLE.LOG "RED"?
  console.log();
});
```

How to use variable color inside controller?

Answer (score 0):

If the `color` parameter will be updated in your directive you need to use two-way binding on your directive - so instead of `@` when defining your `color` parameter you would use `=`. Instead of hardcoding `red` for the `color` parameter you should instead use a controller variable.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
   <tempdir color="selectedColor"></tempdir>
</div>

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive("tempdir", function() {
  return {
    template: "<div id={{color}}> ... </div>",
    scope: {
      color: "="
    }
  };
});

app.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedColor = 'red';
  console.log($scope.selectedColor);
});
```